# Having trouble building my Android ReactJs Native App

Tags: java, android, reactjs, gradle

I'm simply following the guide on the official site: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

**Command:**

```
C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Android Projects\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
```

**Full Error:**

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug...
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configur
ation failure takes precedence.
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir
 in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(Sdk
Handler.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getSdkLoader(SdkHandler.
java:112)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.ja
va:86)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groo
vy:507)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.gro
ovy:455)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.
doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.
doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:
90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(C
losureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaC
lassSite.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaC
lassSite.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:112)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRe
corders.groovy:52)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.ja
va:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMet
hodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMeta
MethodSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:124)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRe
corders.groovy:54)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(Bas
ePlugin.groovy:414)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:
90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(C
losureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(Cl
osureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(Cl
osureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatc
h.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatc
h.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocat
ionHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfte
rEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:487)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:85)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Android Projects\AwesomeProject\android\app\
build.gradle' line: 110

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties f
ile or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.626 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Android Projects\AwesomeProject>
```

**Important Part:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir
     in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

It's complaining that it can't find my Android SDK but I have already pointed to it in my environment variables under `ANDROID_HOME`. For some reason I don't believe this stack trace. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: That variable isn't reliable. Instead, `Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file`

Comment: Or, prove you can `echo` that variable in the terminal

Comment: echo ANDROID_HOME just gives ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: @cricket_007 How do I do that? Which folder should I add this file to?

Comment: No... `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`. Anyway, this error message is very common to Android Getting Started, so I trust you can find resources where that file goes

Comment: ``echo %ANDROID_HOME%`` just returns ``echo %ANDROID_HOME%``, not the directory. I also looked up the problem but it's not solved. I created an ``application.properties`` file in ``C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Android Projects\AwesomeProject\android`` and added the sdk path manually: ``sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\mnxe\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk``. Stil doesn't work.

Comment: `local.properties`... Not application. And if the echo didn't work work, then the error doesn't lie. You need to restart the CMD after setting environmental variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by creating a file called `local.properties` in the directory `C:\Users\mnxe\Documents\Android Projects\AwesomeProject\android` with single line of content: `sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\mnxe\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`.

[image]

Btw, really cool to be able to develop your UI with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.